# properly assign cookies with requests module

Tags: python, python-requests, session-cookies

> > I have found the solution to my syntax error, however I do not understand why original code did not work.

I have tried multiple different modules, like `urllib`, `requests`, and even `sockets`. however i was directed to use `requests` for its simplicity and accuracy. I do not want to give alot of info away as this was a challenge on HTB, however the people i have reached out too just tell me "ya man your syntax looks fine" and are no help....bah. If i need to remove post due to spoilers I will do so immediately.

Thee below snippet worked

```py
import requests
import hashlib
s = requests.session()
url = 'someURL'
r = s.get(url)
cookie = s.cookies.get_dict() ##CHANGING THIS WORKED
x = r.text[167:187] #grabbing specific string
a = hashlib.md5(x.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest() ### CHANGING THIS WORKED
# b = s.post(url, data=a, cookies={'PHPSESSID': '{cookie}'})
final = s.post(url, data={'hash':a}, cookies=cookie)
print(final.text)
```

I am expecting the PHPSESSID to be passed in cookie form back to the server during the request. the above syntax works, however this does not...

```py
import requests
import hashlib
s = requests.session()
url = 'someURL'
r = s.get(url)
cookie = s.cookies['PHPSESSID']
x = r.text[167:187]
h = hashlib.md5()
h.update(x)
a = h.hexdigest()
b = s.post(url, data=a, cookies={'PHPSESSID': '{cookie}'})
print(b.text)
```

what if i wanted to assign myself a cookie? I dont understand how `get_dict()` is working and the other is not.

Comment: If you're trying to create an f-string with `{cookie}`, your missing the `f` prefix

Comment: ~~could you elaborate on that a bit?~~ in the above 2/2 snippet I am setting the cookie to == s.cookie['PHPSESSID'] which does return me a value. are you talking about formatting it during the s.post??

Comment: Try changing `cookies={'PHPSESSID': '{cookie}'}` -> `cookies={'PHPSESSID': cookie}`

Comment: ive tried that before. No bueno.

Comment: Thanks for your help abdusco

Comment: I was wondering, should i update the question title as its not a cookie issue?? but rather a hashlib module issue?

Comment: so the question now is "why the second part does not work", right?

Comment: the second snippet of code in the question will work if i change the way hashlib handles the string `x`.

for instance, instead of:
`h = hashlib.md5(); h.update(x); a = h.hexdigest();`
Do something like:
`h = hashlib.md5(x.encode('utf-8)).hexdigest()`

Comment: the cookies method actually worked both times..Im actually really curious about how the devs feel this is `python zen` appropriate. from my little wee knowledge of python, my understanding is that `'utf-8'` encoding is standard. if that is the case, wouldnt it be more "pythonic" to treat `x.encode()` as you would `.hexdigest()` in this situation??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The cookie is actually passed correctly in both situations. the key difference being the way the `hashlib` module handles `unicode-objects`.

**Solution**
because `x` is a unicode-object, I have to encode it before its sent to `hexdigest()`
that is why

```py
h = hashlib.md5(x.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
```

works and the other does not. simply encoding x will work.